# GCP Pubsub push notification FIFO queue does not wait for acknowledgement

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have two application one system which pushes an event, the other system consumes it and once processed return result of the event.

My understanding after reading the document that there are no guarantees that subsequent messages will be sent without the previous ones being acknowledged. Can this be averted somehow, even though there is no guarantees?

Could this be averted with pull notifications also when the systems are hosted in separated gcp folders ?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the documentation to which you are referring? Your statement "no guarantees that subsequent messages will be sent without the previous ones being acknowledged" is unclear. Are you trying to ensure that prior messages *are* acked before subsequent ones are sent to the subscriber or that the are *not acked* prior to subsequent ones being sent to the subscriber?

Comment: Did you have a look to the ordering key?

Comment: Yes I want the prior message to be acknowledged before subsequent message with the same ordering key is processed. This is the document I am reffering to this doc https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering.  To elaborate I have two events e1 and e2 with the same ordering key (lets say o1). I want e1 to be  acknowledged and then e2 to be processesed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For push subscriptions, a subsequent message for an ordering key cannot be sent to the push endpoint until the previous message is acknowledged. With push subscriptions, this is the only way Pub/Sub can guarantee messages are sent in order since each push request is for a single message.

When using pull subscriptions, multiple messages are sent in a single response and therefore the subscriber could receive multiple messages for the same ordering key without previous ones having been acknowledged (though they will be received in order).

It is still important to ensure you use a relatively diverse set of ordering keys. In other words, one should not use a single ordering key as a means to attain total ordering on the entire topic. To do so would limit throughput and availability.